# Writing to a file and getting weird indentation

Tags: python

I have the following snippet of code, which takes a url opens it, parses out JUST the text and then searches for widgets. The way it detects widgets is by looking for the word `widget1` and then `endwidget`, which denotes the end of the widget.

Basically the code writes all lines of text to a file as soon as it finds the word `widget1` and ends when it reads `endwidget`. However, my code is indenting all lines after the first `widget1` line.

This is my output

```
widget1 this is a really cool widget
       it does x, y and z 
       and also a, b and c
       endwidget
```

What I want is:

```
widget1 this is a really cool widget
it does x, y and z 
and also a, b and c
endwidget
```

Why am I getting this indentation? This is my code...

```
 for url in urls:
        page = mech.open(url)
        html = page.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        text= soup.prettify()
        texts = soup.findAll(text=True) 

        def visible(element):
            if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']: 
            # If the parent of your element is any of those ignore it

                return False

            elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
            # If the element matches an html tag, ignore it

                return False

            else:
            # Otherwise, return True as these are the elements we need

              return True

        visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)

        inwidget=0
        # open a file for write
        for line in visible_texts:
        # if line doesn't contain .widget1 then ignore it
            if ".widget1" in line and inwidget==0:
                match = re.search(r'\.widget1 (\w+)', line)
                line = line.split (".widget1")[1]   
                # make the next word after .widget1 the name of the file
                filename = "%s" % match.group(1) + ".txt"
                textfile = open (filename, 'w+b')
                textfile.write("source:" + url + "\n\n")
                textfile.write(".widget1" + line)
                inwidget = 1
            elif inwidget == 1 and ".endwidget" not in line:
                print line
                textfile.write(line)
            elif ".endwidget" in line and inwidget == 1:
                textfile.write(line)
                inwidget= 0
            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this indentation in all lines except for the first is because the first line you edit the line with `textfile.write(".widget1" + line)` but the rest of the lines you take directly from the html file where it contains indentation. You can remove the unwanted white spaces by using [str.strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on the lines and change `textfile.write(line)` to `textfile.write(line.strip())`.

Answer (score 0):

To go from your output to your wanted output, do this:

```
#a is your output
a= '\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.strip(),a.split('\n')))
```

Comment: Thanks, is `a` supposed to be the variable `texts` or is it each `line in visible_texts`

Comment: Also, what exactly is it doing? it's stripping the carriage return and what else?

Comment: It is splitting on the \n, making a list of strings, each for each line, then each line is stripped (meaning it removes the spaces at the beginning and at the end.. but you could change it to strip only at the beginning with lstrip) and then the strings are joined together again using \n as separator.

Comment: Oh i forgot to join back actually

Comment: The other solution seems easier to me so going to go with that. Sorry. Thanks for answering.